# What is the name of two points that share the two coordinate?

Tags: coordinate-systems

Is there an adjective to characterize two points that have the same coordinates. 
$A(x_1,y_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2)$, where $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$.

Comment: Yes, the adjective is *equal*, which means they are the same.

Comment: Could I say that the two points are congruent?

Comment: Depending on the context, another possibility is *coincident*

Comment: Informally *congruent* means "same shape and size, though possibly in a different place" and more formally one set of points which can transformed to another with an isometry (a distance-preserving transformation).  So it is probably not useful here as typically any two points are congruent to each other even with different locations

Comment: @AliTarek In mathematics people use certain natural language words (like equal, congruent, increasing, etc), always as a shorthand for a complicated sequence of symbols. Some of these sequence of symbols are so useful used so much, that people give them names, like the ones mentioned above. *Congruent* is a term usually reserved for line segments, polygons, etc. I don't think I have ever seen the word *congruence* for points, probably because it isn't very useful. You could give it a natural definition as it meaning they are equal, but so what? What do you get out of it?

Answer (score 1):

My inclination is to call the points "coincident," as Henry suggests, seeing as that fits nicely with two points lying on the same line being called "colinear" and two points or two lines lying in the same plane being called "coplanar."

That said, I don't think I've heard "coincident" used in that sense formally, nor have I heard any other word specifically used to describe two points with the same coordinates. I assume most people would understand what you mean were you to use it in that sense, though.